# Applying the fundamental theorem of Integration

Tags: integration

We know from the fundamental theorem of Integration that for a continuous function

$ f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $

with antiderivative

$ f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $

we have that

$ \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(t) dt = F(x_2) - F(x_1) $

From the fundamental theorem of Integration we can say that the derivative of $F(x)$

where $ F(x) = \int_{0}^{sin(x^2)} \exp\left(\frac{1}{5t-9}\right) $

is simply

$ \exp\left(\frac{1}{5(sin(x^2))-9}\right) $

My question is, how do you connect the fundamental theorem of Integration with the method we used above for finding the derivative?

Comment: The derivative above is incorrect. It is missing a $2x \cos x^2$ term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the chain rule. You have $$f(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \exp(\frac{1}{5t-9})$$ and
$$g(x) = \sin (x^2)$$. Then $$F(x) = f(g(x))$$, and
$$F'(x) = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$$ by the chain rule.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.

Comment: I wish :-). Glad to be able to help!